# Prove: $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}\cup \{(0,1)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open/close and the limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

To show $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}\cup \{(0,1)\}$ is open we need to show that for every arbitrary $p\in A$ there is $r>$ such that $B(p,r)\subset B$

But there is no such $r>0$ for the point $(0,1)\in A$ so $A$ is not open.

To prove $A$ is closed we need to show that $A^{c}=(\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}\cup \{(0,1)\})^{c}=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\geq 1\}\cap \{(0,1)\}$ is open

How can I do that?

As for the limit points I think that there are all $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$

Is showing that $lim_{k\to \infty}(\frac{k-1}{k},0)=(1,0)$ enough?

Comment: Yes, for the closed part, that seems correct. Set is definitely not closed if, of course, we're referring to the standard euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @MathNewbie I have not shown that it is closed

Comment: It's not closed.

Comment: @MathNewbie ok then I have to show that $A^{c}$ is not open

Comment: From above, you just gave an example of a sequence in $A$ that approximates $(1,0)$ but $(1,0)$ is not in $A$.

Comment: @MathNewbie so $A$ is not closed because not all its limit point contained in $A$?

Comment: That's correct  (of course in a metric space).

Comment: I believe $A^C=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\geq 1\}\cap \{(0,1)\}^C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set is neither open or closed. I think that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$

Take $(-1,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. You can take a sequence $\{x_k\}\subseteq A$ such that $\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}x_k=(-1,0)$ but $(-1,0)\notin A$

The limit points of A are $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. Only you should to prove that exist a sequence such that converges to the points on $\partial(X)$ (the boundary).

Hint: Think in the distance between the points on $\partial(X)$ and the points in $A$. The sequence that you need is determined by this.

Comment: maybe: $lim_{k\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+y^2-\frac{1}{k}}\leq 1$? where $(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1$

Comment: I think in the sequence $x_k=\left\{ \left( a,\displaystyle\frac{1}{k},b-\displaystyle\frac{1}{k} \right)\right\}$ where $a^2+b^2=1$. Only you prove that the distance between $\left( a,\displaystyle\frac{1}{k},b-\displaystyle\frac{1}{k} \right)$ and $(0,0)$ is less than 1. With this, we conclude that $\{x_k\}\subseteq A$.